# Custom Component in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a custom component and registered it. But I get in the browser a warning, which I cannot process. In my opinion it is properly registered?

> vue.js:435 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you
>   register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure
>   to provide the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->

**Main**

```
import GISView from './components/GISView.vue';
import VueEvents from 'vue-events';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueEvents)

var App = window.App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'gisview': GISView
  },
    data() {
        return {
            eventData: {
                foo: 'baz'
            }
        }
    },
  methods: {
    init: function() {
      this.$events.$emit("test", this.eventData);
    }
  }
});
```

**Component**

```
<template>
    <div ref="map" id="map" class="google-map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <gisview></gisview>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import GoogleMaps from '../mixins/GoogleMaps.js';

    export default {
        mixins: [GoogleMaps],

        mounted() {
            console.log("Mounted");
            this.$events.$on('test', eventData => console.log("Fired"));
        },

        data: function() {
            return {
                eventData: {
                    foo: 'baz'
                }
            }
        },

        methods: {
            initMap: function() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(this.$els.map, {
                    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                    zoom: 8
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Usage**

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div id="app">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="ibox">
                        <div class="ibox-title">GIS</div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <gisview></gisview>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I see 1-2 problems here.

1. You registered `GISView` to `App.vue` **locally**, meaning you can only use `<gisview>` inside `App.vue`'s template. You *can* register `GISView` globally, like so, but i doubt you would want that.

`Vue.component(GISView)`

2. Is your second code example supposed to be `GISView.vue`? If it is, you're trying to use `<gisview>` within itself. Recursive components are a thing, but i don't think that's what you're going for here.